# Wortgruppen finden

Tags: dictionary

Ich suche immer wieder Wörter einer bestimmten Gruppe, z.B. Bewegungsverben (laufen, springen, schreiten usw.) oder Gebäudeteile (Tür, Keller, Trakt usw.).

Gibt es – möglichst umfassende – Wörterbücher oder Wortlisten, die eine derartige Sortierung nach Bedeutungskategorien erlauben?

Ich suche keine Synonyme! Tür, Keller und Trakt sind keine Synonyme und werden in einen Thesaurus nicht gemeinsam verzeichnet.

Ein Beispiel ist Dornseif, [*Der deutsche Wortschatz nach Sachgruppen*](http://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/61548). Leider ist dieses Buch – eben weil es ein Buch ist – sehr unflexibel und erlaubt neben der gedruckten Ordnung keine anderen Kategorisierungen.

Comment: Alle Wörterbücher erlauben das. Du kannst es jederzeit machen ;). Warum sagst du nicht einfach "haben" oder wenn's denn kompliziert sein muss "aufweisen"

Comment: Ich verstehe deinen Kommentar zu "haben" und "aufweisen" nicht. Was hat das mit meinem Wunsch zu tun, Wörter nach Bedeutungskategorien zu sortieren?

Comment: Haven't heard of such a dictionary, but hat doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @koljanep See my edit.

Comment: Ich fand die Formulierung "Wörterbücher, die etwas erlauben" komisch. Wahrscheinlich (wie mir jetzt klar wurde) weil ich an richtige Bücher gedacht habe. Die haben entweder eine solche Sortierung oder eben nicht. Das Verb "erlauben" wäre da fehl am Platz. Bei Online-Wörterbüchern ist das natürlich anders, aber das war nicht meine Assoziation.

Answer (score 2):

Ein solches Wörterbuch heißt **Thesaurus**. Es gibt sie in gedruckter Form, aber Google findet auch einige Online-Versionen, z.B. [hier](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/laufen) oder [hier](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/laufen.php).

Wenn man nicht nur Synonyme haben will, sondern eine größere Begriffsgruppe, kann man die transitive Hülle bilden: Synonyme von Synonymen solange mit einbeziehen, bis die Gruppe groß genug ist.

Roget's Thesaurus ordnet die Begriffe auch in einer [Hierarchie](http://www.roget.org/hierarchy.htm), für Bewegung siehe z.B. #264 ff. Ich weiß nicht, ob es das auf Deutsch gibt, aber notfalls kann man die englischen Begriffe übersetzen und hat dann auch eine recht große Gruppe.

Answer (score 0):

Eine thematische Ordnung der Einträge gibt es in Bildwörterbüchern.

So findet man beispielsweise im *Duden Bildwörterbuch* unter der Überschrift **Küche** die folgenden Stichworte:

> der Mikrowellenherd, der Kühlschrank, das Kühlfach, die Gemüseschale, das Gefrierfach, das Türfach für Flaschen, der Gefrierschrank (Tiefgefrierschrank), der Oberschrank (Hängeschrank), ein Geschirrschrank, der Unterschrank, die Besteckschublade, der Hauptarbeitsplatz (Vorbereitungsplatz), der Koch- und Backplatz, der Elektroherd (auch: Gasherd), der Backofen, das Backofenfenster, die Kochplatte (automatische Schnellkochplatte), der Wasserkessel (Flötenkessel), der Wrasenabzug (Dunstabzug), der Topflappen, der Topflappenhalter, die Küchenuhr
>   der Kurzzeitmesser, das Handrührgerät (der Handrührer), der Schlagbesen, die elektrische Kaffeemühle, eine Schlagwerkkaffeemühle, die elektrische Zuleitung (das Leitungskabel), die Wandsteckdose, der Eckschrank, das Drehtablett, der Kochtopf, die Kanne, das Gewürzregal, das Gewürzglas, der Spülplatz, der Abtropfständer, der Frühstücksteller, die Geschirrspüle (Spüle, das Spülbecken), der Wasserhahn (die Wassermischbatterie), die Topfpflanze, eine Blattpflanze, die Kaffeemaschine (der Kaffeeautomat), die Küchenlampe, der Geschirrspüler (Geschirrspülautomat, Geschirrspülmaschine), der Geschirrwagen, der Essteller, der Küchenstuhl, der Küchentisch, der Toaster

Als anderes Beispiel findet man im *Duden Bildwörterbuch für Kinder* unter **Eigenschaften:**

> dünn, dick, groß, klein, schnell, langsam, böse, lieb, neu, alt, schön, hässlich, laut, leise, schwer, leicht, kalt, warm, richtig, falsch, schmutzig, sauber, krank, gesund, traurig, lustig

Naturgemäß ist allerdings der Stichwortumfang von Bildwörterbüchern stark begrenzt. Außerdem ist die Sortierung in gedruckten Büchern weitgehend festgelegt. Bildwörterbücher leisten daher vermutlich nicht, was mit der Fragestellung erhofft wird.